# Laravel I can't retrieve requester data using with

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using this package
https://github.com/renoki-co/befriended
My issue is trying to get all my friends posts with my post including user's data, but the problem is the requester data is null.

```
      $user = $request->user();
        $followersPost = UserPost::with(['user' => function ($query) use ($user) {
            $query->filterFollowingsOf($user);
        }])->latest()->get();
        return $followersPost;
```

Response

```
[
{
"id": 35,
"post_body": "The Requster Post",
"location_id": "4b0da1acf964a520b94c23e3",
"location_title": "Apple Infinite Loop",
"location_icon": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/technology_bg_44.png",
"location_coordinate": "{"latitude":37.33167558501772,"longitude":-122.030189037323,"latitudeDelta":0.001,"longitudeDelta":0.001}",
"location_vicinity": "Cupertino - 1 Infinite Loop",
"user_id": 1,
"viewer_ids": null,
"created_at": "2020-12-06T18:08:58.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-12-06T18:08:58.000000Z",
"images": [
],
"musics": [
],
"movies": [
],
"emojs": [
],
"user": null
},
{
"id": 34,
"post_body": "Test Post",
"location_id": "4b0da1acf964a520b94c23e3",
"location_title": "Apple Infinite Loop",
"location_icon": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/shops/technology_bg_44.png",
"location_coordinate": "{"latitude":37.33167558501772,"longitude":-122.030189037323,"latitudeDelta":0.001,"longitudeDelta":0.001}",
"location_vicinity": "Cupertino - 1 Infinite Loop",
"user_id": 2,
"viewer_ids": null,
"created_at": "2020-12-06T18:08:14.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-12-06T18:08:14.000000Z",
"images": [
],
"musics": [
],
"movies": [
],
"emojs": [
],
"user": {
"id": 2,
"_id": "dfa19aa6-510b-4aaf-8475-4386da9de3d0",
"name": "Saleh",
"username": "saleh",
"email": "saleh@gmail.com",
"email_verified_at": null,
"avatar": "http://backend.mf.sa/storage/avatars/1607128041.jpg",
"location": null,
"gender": "male",
"bio": null,
"birthday": null,
"phone": null,
"created_at": "2020-12-05T00:27:02.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-12-05T00:27:21.000000Z"
}
},
{
"id": 24,
"post_body": null,
"location_id": null,
"location_title": null,
"location_icon": null,
"location_coordinate": null,
"location_vicinity": null,
"user_id": 3,
"viewer_ids": null,
"created_at": "2020-12-06T01:53:18.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-12-06T01:53:18.000000Z",
"images": [
],
"musics": [
{
"id": 4,
"post_id": 24,
"song_name": "Confetti",
"song_preview": "https://cdns-preview-6.dzcdn.net/stream/c-6eb643a05083c023f874f13739fc7c87-3.mp3",
"song_picture": "https://api.deezer.com/album/183603832/image",
"song_artist": "Little Mix",
"created_at": "2020-12-06T01:53:18.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-12-06T01:53:18.000000Z"
}
],
"movies": [
],
"emojs": [
{
"id": 16,
"post_id": 24,
"user_id": 3,
"emojy": "015-smile-1",
"created_at": "2020-12-06T01:59:15.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-12-06T01:59:15.000000Z",
"user": {
"id": 3,
"_id": "af65864b-f18a-4609-91db-336acbce1486",
"name": "Ali",
"username": "ali2323",
"email": "ali@gmail.com",
"email_verified_at": null,
"avatar": null,
"location": null,
"gender": "male",
"bio": null,
"birthday": null,
"phone": null,
"created_at": "2020-12-05T04:05:50.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-12-05T04:05:50.000000Z"
}
},
{
"id": 17,
"post_id": 24,
"user_id": 1,
"emojy": "089-broken-heart",
"created_at": "2020-12-06T16:58:07.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-12-06T16:58:24.000000Z",
"user": {
"id": 1,
"_id": "737ba284-424d-4b0d-8a56-2e845603f2ba",
"name": "Mohammed",
"username": "mohammed",
"email": "h4ck3r.x0@gmail.com",
"email_verified_at": null,
"avatar": "http://backend.mf.sa/storage/avatars/1607128001.jpg",
"location": null,
"gender": "male",
"bio": null,
"birthday": null,
"phone": null,
"created_at": "2020-12-05T00:26:09.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-12-05T00:26:41.000000Z"
}
},
{
"id": 19,
"post_id": 24,
"user_id": 2,
"emojy": "021-sad",
"created_at": "2020-12-06T16:58:36.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-12-06T16:58:36.000000Z",
"user": {
"id": 2,
"_id": "dfa19aa6-510b-4aaf-8475-4386da9de3d0",
"name": "Saleh",
"username": "saleh",
"email": "saleh@gmail.com",
"email_verified_at": null,
"avatar": "http://backend.mf.sa/storage/avatars/1607128041.jpg",
"location": null,
"gender": "male",
"bio": null,
"birthday": null,
"phone": null,
"created_at": "2020-12-05T00:27:02.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-12-05T00:27:21.000000Z"
}
}
],
"user": {
"id": 3,
"_id": "af65864b-f18a-4609-91db-336acbce1486",
"name": "Ali",
"username": "ali2323",
"email": "ali@gmail.com",
"email_verified_at": null,
"avatar": null,
"location": null,
"gender": "male",
"bio": null,
"birthday": null,
"phone": null,
"created_at": "2020-12-05T04:05:50.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-12-05T04:05:50.000000Z"
}
}
]
```

As you can see the first object in the array dosen't include the user data.
So what should i do  `$query->filterFollowingsOf($user);` to include my data?

Comment: I see you logged an issue on their repo, let's see what they say?

Comment: i've did it. check out the issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `with` callback is used for modifying the query that selects the user data. Instead, try using a `whereHas` method that filters the related users.

```php
$user = $request->user();

$followersPost = UserPost
    ::with('user')
    ->whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->filterFollowingsOf($user);
    })
    ->latest()
    ->get();


return $followersPost;
```

I'd also recommend using `paginate()` instead of `get()` for performance when there could be a significant number of posts.

**Edit:**

To get either your friend's posts or your posts, try:

```php
$followersPost = UserPost
    ::with('user')
    ->whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->filterFollowingsOf($user);
    })
    ->orWhere('user_id', $user->id)
    ->latest()
    ->get();
```

Comment: that's also worked only for my friends posts but my posts dosen't show.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you can get your friend's posts and your own posts